# Dynamic pivot of Row Value to Column header in Hive

Tags: date, hive, transpose

I have date value row wise like in this format

```
7/7/2017
7/14/2017
7/21/2017
7/28/2017
8/4/2017
8/11/2017
8/18/2017
8/25/2017
9/1/2017
9/8/2017
9/15/2017
9/22/2017
9/29/2017
10/6/2017
10/13/2017
10/20/2017
10/27/2017
11/3/2017
11/10/2017
11/17/2017
11/24/2017
12/1/2017
12/8/2017
12/15/2017
12/22/2017
12/29/2017
```

I want to transform it as column header without manually entering each value in my Hive code. Can i able to do it if yes please help me out.

Comment: Do you want each date value as a column in a Hive table?

Comment: Yes but it should be dynamically

Comment: write some python or any program which you are aware of and give the values as input and dynamically add the columns in the create table command. As far as I aware of there is no other way.

Comment: @Sourav have you got any solutions for this ? am looking for same

Comment: @BD No, I did not find any solution. But I made work around using excel